# iOS push notification with PyAPNs

Tags: python, ios, push-notification

I'm trying to send push notification from my Python server to my iOS application, copy paste the sample code in Git.

```
from apns import APNs, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='MyAppCert.pem', key_file='MyAppKey.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = MY_TOKEN_NUMBER
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

When calling the api from the browser I get the following error:

```
SSLError: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0002:SSLroutines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
```

1. Where should I store the MyAppCert.pem MyAppKey.pem on the server?
2. beside placing them in a folder do I need to do something else?
3. should I set the entire path?